# Link jira id against each feature in Cucumber testing report

Tags: cucumber, jira

Have started using cucumber framework for testing of my project.
Able to generate cucumber html , json and xml report.

I am looking for something like JIRA ID link to be represented against feature representation in report.

Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used tags to represent JIRA tickets in scenarios/features. For example, if you have a JIRA ticket with ID JIRA-123, your scenario could look like this:

```
@JIRA-123
Scenario: ...
```

You should then be able to see from the cucumber reports which features/scenarios are marked with which tags. You can build a custom report that fetches all the JIRA tags and retrieves ticket information from JIRA in runtime using for example JS and the JIRA API.

Answer (score 0):

A major flaw in what you are trying to do is that Jira tickets are historical whilst scenarios are current.

Jira tickets document what was being done at a particular time in the projects lifecyle whilst scenarios document the current state of the application.

Scenarios have current knowledge of the application. Jira tickets only have the knowledge that was available when they were created.

Trying to link these two very different things has some negative consequences including:

1. You stop people from refactoring scenarios to reflect the current state of the application, because they need to maintain the links with the jira history.
2. Your links mislead, a scenario changes over time to reflect the current application but your links imply that what is in the jira ticket still applies.
3. Link management becomes very confusing, scenarios end up with multiple links and links get removed or applied to un-related scenarios as refactoring takes place.

Point 1 is particularly important. Scenarios can very easily become slow, unreliable and unwieldy. They can significantly increase the cost of change for an application unless they are very well managed. Anything that stops this management is detrimental.